# Moving maven profiles in setting.xml to pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am using maven3. I have some user specific profiles and activeProfiles tags defined in settings.xml and I want to move them to project's pom.xml.
But merely copying profiles and activeProfiles from settings.xml to pom.xml does not work and breaks build because it tries to find project's parent pom in maven central instead of artifactory. Here's my settings.xml profiles.
Maven reports problem: 
Failure to find xxx:xxx:pom:19.2 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Can someone please help ?

```
{

    <profiles>
        <profile>
          <id>group</id>
          <repositories>
            <repository>
              <id>nb_releases</id>
              <name>Releases</name>
              <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
              </releases>
              <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
              </snapshots>
              <url>http://artifactory.xxxx.xxxx/nb-m2</url>
              <layout>default</layout>
            </repository>
          </repositories>
        </profile>

        <profile>
          <id>snapshots-group</id>
          <repositories>
            <repository>
              <id>nb_snapshots</id>
              <name>Snapshots</name>
              <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
              </releases>
              <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
              </snapshots>
              <url>http://artifactory.xxxx.xxxx/nb-m2-snapshot</url>
              <layout>default</layout>
            </repository>
          </repositories>
        </profile>
        <profile>
          <id>plugins</id>
            <pluginRepositories>
              <pluginRepository>
                <id>nb_plugins</id>
                <name>Plugins</name>
                <releases>
                  <enabled>true</enabled>
                  <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                  <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy> 
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                  <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <url>http://artifactory.xxx.xxx/nb-m2</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
             </pluginRepository>
          </pluginRepositories>
      </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
      <activeProfile>group</activeProfile>
      <activeProfile>snapshots-group</activeProfile>
      <activeProfile>plugins</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag `<activeProfiles>` can only be used in the `settings.xml`, not in the POM.

There are different possibilities to activate a profile which can be used in a POM:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: Thanks JK Meier. I added 'activation' tag in pom within profile and that solved.

`
<profile>
      <id>plugins</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
      <pluginRepositories> 
    ...
`